# Javascript - Reemplazo de caracteres con expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Estoy creando una forma personalizada de trabajar con CSS desde Javascript. Dado el siguiente string:

```
'Bg:$Color1; Pos:absolute; Inset:0px; Margin:$Medida1'
```

Mi objetivo es reemplazar cada '$' por 'var(--' y buscar el próximo caracter no alfanumérico (un punto y coma, un espacio, etc.) para agregar el paréntesis de cierre ')' antes de ese caracter. Obteniendo esto:

```
'Bg:var(--Color1); Pos:absolute; Inset:0px; Margin:var(--Medida1)'
```

Puedo hacer esto perfectamente usando whiles, fors, índices. Lo que hago luego con el resultado no es el objetivo de esta pregunta ;-).

Mi pregunta es: ¿puedo hacer esto mediante expresiones regulares?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El regex es prácticamente lo mismo que escribiste en la pregunta:

```
/\$([a-z0-9]+)/gi
```

Es decir, un símbolo de pesos literal `\$`, seguido de uno o más alfanuméricos `[a-z0-9]+`.

Los paréntesis capturan al texto, de modo que esté grabado en `$1` para el reemplazo: `(--$1)`.

```js
const regex = /\$([a-z0-9]+)/gi;
const reempl = `(--$1)`;

const texto = `Bg:$Color1; Pos:absolute; Inset:0px; Margin:$Medida1`;
   
const rta = texto.replace(regex, reempl);

console.log(rta);
```